# Webscrape Multiple Pages with python - output issue

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-beautifultable

Happy new year python community,

I am trying to extract a table from website using Python Beautifulsoup4

I am struggling to see the results in my output files.
The code run smoothly but nothing is written the file.

My code below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq
import re

base_url = 'http://www.creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value='
r = rq.get(base_url)

soup = bsoup(r.text)
# Use regex to isolate only the links of the page numbers, the one you click on.
page_count_links = soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile(r".http://www.creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value=&page=.*"))
try: # Make sure there are more than one page, otherwise, set to 1.
    num_pages = int(page_count_links[-1].get_text())
except IndexError:
    num_pages = 1

# Add 1 because Python range.
url_list = ["{}&page={}".format(base_url, str(page)) for page in range(1, 3)]

# Open the text file. Use with to save self from grief.
with open("results.txt","wb") as acct:
    for url_ in url_list:
        print("Processing {}...".format(url_))
        r_new = rq.get(url_)
        soup_new = bsoup(r_new.text)
        for tr in soup_new.find_all('tr', align='center'):
            stack = []
            for td in tr.findAll('td'):
                stack.append(td.text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').strip())
            acct.write(", ".join(stack) + '\n')
```

Comment: you're missing your indent after `except IndexError:`

Comment: actually the statement is num_pages = 1. I made a mistake when copying my code

Comment: ya saw that. quickly changed my comment to missing the indent. but still working through the code, as you're right, not getting an output

Comment: I'm getting a response 404 because the page you're using as `url_` is not found. Check that you haven't a typo there or something

Comment: Just update the url, Now it should be OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`soup_new.find_all('tr', align='center')` returns an empty list

Try switching that for `for tr in soup_new.find_all('tr'):`

and secondly, since you're using strings, switch the mode `with open("results.txt","wb")` to `with open("results.txt","w")`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq
import re

base_url = 'http://www.creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value=&page=2'
r = rq.get(base_url)

soup = bsoup(r.text)
# Use regex to isolate only the links of the page numbers, the one you click on.
page_count_links = soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile(r".http://www.creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value=&page=.*"))
try: # Make sure there are more than one page, otherwise, set to 1.
    num_pages = int(page_count_links[-1].get_text())
except IndexError:
    num_pages = 1

# Add 1 because Python range.
url_list = ["{}&page={}".format(base_url, str(page)) for page in range(1, 3)]

# Open the text file. Use with to save self from grief.
with open("results.txt","w") as acct:
    for url_ in url_list:

        #url_ = url_list[0]

        print("Processing {}...".format(url_))
        r_new = rq.get(url_)
        soup_new = bsoup(r_new.text)


        for tr in soup_new.find_all('tr'):
            stack = []
            for td in tr.findAll('td'):
                stack.append(td.text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').strip())
            acct.write(", ".join(stack) + '\n')
```

Comment: just edited the url but still not writing the data...
i think as you mentioned the issue is soup_new.find_all('tr', align='center') but still dont know how to fix this

Comment: ya, found it. Check the answer above. Worked for me. Wrote to file

Comment: What did you changed in the code? still not writing for me

Comment: `for tr in soup_new.find_all('tr'):` and `with open("results.txt","w"):`

Comment: also, `with open("results.txt","w"):` will save the file under the current working directory. I like to have the file go in specified so I'm not suprised/looking around for it. so you could explicitly include the path of a folder you want that in. But it works on my end. What errors are you getting?

Comment: great. glad it works. make sure to accept the answer above