# scrape table from multiple pages and add data from links

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am quite new to python and i want your light on a problem.
I want to scrape the table from this link : http://creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value=

As you can see in the website, in the last column, there is a link called "Voir détails" on each line.
Actually i want to create 3 new columns: "Region", "Capital" and "Objet Social" that we get where click on the link and add to the table with the general information.

My code already extract the table in the different pages

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq
import re

base_url = 'http://www.creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value='
r = rq.get(base_url)

soup = bsoup(r.text)

page_count_links = soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile(r".http://www.creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value=&page=.*"))
try: 
    num_pages = int(page_count_links[-1].get_text())
except IndexError:
    num_pages = 1


url_list = ["{}&page={}".format(base_url, str(page)) for page in range(1, 3)]

with open("results.txt","w") as acct:
    for url_ in url_list:
        print("Processing {}...".format(url_))
        r_new = rq.get(url_)
        soup_new = bsoup(r_new.text)
        for tr in soup_new.find_all('tr'): 
            stack = []
            for td in tr.findAll('td'):
                stack.append(td.text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').strip())
            acct.write(", ".join(stack) + '\n')
```

My query can return the table:

Dénomination - Date Création - Siège social - Forme Juridique - Secteur d'activité.

how could shift my script to have 3 new columns like :

Dénomination - Date Création - Siège social - Forme Juridique - Secteur d'activité - Region - Capital - Objet Social

Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to extract the link and parse the html of that link. Essentially you'll have a nested loop, that is much in the same way as you have your initial loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq
import re

base_url = 'http://www.creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value='
r = rq.get(base_url)

soup = bsoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

page_count_links = soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile(r".http://www.creationdentreprise.sn/rechercher-une-societe?field_rc_societe_value=&field_ninea_societe_value=&denomination=&field_localite_nid=All&field_siege_societe_value=&field_forme_juriduqe_nid=All&field_secteur_nid=All&field_date_crea_societe_value=&page=.*"))
try: 
    num_pages = int(page_count_links[-1].get_text())
except IndexError:
    num_pages = 1


url_list = ["{}&page={}".format(base_url, str(page)) for page in range(1, 3)]

with open("results.txt","w") as acct:
    for url_ in url_list:
        print("Processing {}...".format(url_))
        r_new = rq.get(url_)
        soup_new = bsoup(r_new.text)
        for tr in soup_new.find_all('tr'): 
            stack = []

            # set link_ext to None
            link_ext = None

            # try to get link in last column. If not present, pass
            try:
                link_ext = tr.select('a')[-1]['href']
            except:
                pass

            for td in tr.findAll('td'):
                stack.append(td.text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').strip())

            # if a link was extracted from last column, use it to get html from link and parse wanted data
            if link_ext is not None:
                r_link = rq.get('http://creationdentreprise.sn' + link_ext)
                soup_link_ext = bsoup(r_link.text, 'html.parser')
                region = soup_link_ext.find(text=re.compile('Région:')).parent.nextSibling.text
                capital = soup_link_ext.find(text=re.compile('Capital:')).parent.nextSibling.text
                objet = soup_link_ext.find(text=re.compile('Objet social:')).parent.nextSibling.text

                stack = stack + [region, capital, objet]

            acct.write(", ".join(stack) + '\n')
```

Also, I noticed this yesterday in your first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112264/webscrape-multiple-pages-with-python-output-issue) but didn't mention it, but your `page_count_links` and `num_pages` don't get used for anything in your code. Why have it there?

Just curious, why do you have 2 user accounts, same screen name?

Comment: Thanks you again for your support.
The page_count_links and num_pages  doesn't have much value add in my output for sure. The goal were to use regex to isolate only the links of the page numbers, the one you click on..

PS: Haha will delete the other account. Lazyness catch me up :-)

Comment: no worries. I just got confused because I saw the question and remembered seeing it earlier, so just gave me dejavu. and when I went back to find the question, it was a different user but same screenname...yada, yada, yada. was just curious.